# Template to create IAM role for spectrum S3 access

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

In order to access S3 data through spectrum, I need to create an IAM role as explained here...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html

The newly created IAM role needs to be attached to redshift instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/copy-unload-iam-role.html#copy-unload-iam-role-associating-with-clusters

I have managed to complete all the steps successfully. But I will like to know if a cloudformation template can be written that will be do the needful quickly.
Here is relevant code that I have extracted. I am not sure how to put is in correct syntax.

Step 1

```
{
        "Tags": [],
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "RoleId": "AROAJWJGDMYIHSSTPZ6I6CM",
        "CreateDate": "2017-05-15T05:34:46Z",
        "InstanceProfileList": [],
        "RoleName": "RedshiftCopyUnload",
        "Path": "/",
        "AttachedManagedPolicies": [
            {
                "PolicyName": "AmazonAthenaFullAccess",
                "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAthenaFullAccess"
            },
            {
                "PolicyName": "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess",
                "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"
            },
            {
                "PolicyName": "AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess",
                "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess"
            }
        ],
        "RolePolicyList": [],
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RedshiftCopyUnload"
    }
```

Step 2

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "redshift:DescribeClusters",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                 "redshift:ModifyClusterIamRoles",
                 "redshift:CreateCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                 "arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster:my-redshift-cluster",
                 "arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster:cluster:my-second-redshift-cluster"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SecondRedshiftRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ThirdRedshiftRole"
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Update: will the following cloudformation template correctly create the role mentioned in step 1?

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "NewRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "redshift.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "RoleName": "RedshiftCopyUnload",
        "Path": "/",
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAthenaFullAccess",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "But I will like to know if a cloudformation template can be written that will be do the needful quickly." - I fail to understand the question, could you please try to reformulate it? What is the status quo, what is the problem and what would you like to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. An AWS CloudFormation template can be used to define an IAM Role.

Here is an example from [AWS::IAM::Role - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  RootRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.&api-domain;
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: '*'
                Resource: '*'
```

Comment: How do I include AttachedManagedPolicies? And is there a different template for step 2 or it can be written in a single file?

Comment: As per the documentation, there is a `ManagedPolicyArns` field that can be used. You can associate an IAM Role with a Redshift cluster via the `IamRoles` field on the cluster, but this needs to be specified at the time that the cluster is launched. If you are adding a role _after_ the cluster is launched, you can do it via the AWS CLI, but not a CloudFormation template.

Comment: Is it possible to import the cluster and then update as suggested here? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/

Comment: @shantanuo Theoretically, yes, you should be able to import the resource. However, you might want to test the template to make sure things behave as expected.

Comment: bountifing the question so that someone will help with importing resource to be modified with IAM role!

Comment: As per this page, redshift is not the resource supported for import operation. :( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html